# Async await chaining how to stop

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

(newbie to async/await)

I am chaining an Initialize() function that's being drilled down to many classes.
each class has this initialize method:

```
    public async Task Initialize(string fileName)
```

When I am getting to the final class, what am I supposed to do ?
I want to run a simple function like:

```
public async Task Initialize(string dllPath)
{         
    await PrintThePath(dllPath);
}

public void PrintThePath(string dllPath)
{
     Console.WriteLine(dllPath);
}
```

Of course I am getting "cannot await a void" error.
So I am doing something wrong, logically.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Do you actually have anything to `await`? It sounds like you shouldn't be using `async` at all.

Comment: I have, this is the start, later on this init will instantiate a WCF client who will communicate with WCF service. and the WCF Service will take atleast couple of seconds to complete the action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case just call `PrintThePath` directly without `await` since it's a simple synchronous method.

```
public async Task Initialize(string dllPath)
{
    PrintThePath(dllPath);
}
```

Looking at this sample though there seems to be no reason to mark `Initialize` as `async`.  It doesn't do any `async` work and isn't an `override` method.  There is no need in itself to mark this method as `async` (and the compiler will warn you about this)

**Edit**

OP specified they build with warnings as errors and need to maintain this pattern even though `Initialize` doesn't actually `await`.  Here is the code to suppress the warning

```
#pragma warning disable 1998
    public async Task Initialize(string dllPath)
    {
        PrintThePath(dllPath);
    }
#pragma warning restore 1998
```

Comment: The problem is that i treat warning as errors and can not compile

Comment: @ilansch: Then you need to suppress the warning.

Comment: its not a warning since the project properties is set to: Treat all warning as error.  so this is a conflict :( since i can not suspress an error.

Comment: @ilansch warnings can still be supressed even with `warn as error` enabled.  Simply do a `#pragma warning disable 1998` before the function definition and re-enable it afterwards

Comment: Ok built was fine, thanks, This is not clear, How did you know its 1998 ?

Comment: @ilansch i compiled locally and looked at the warning message.  For this scenario it begins with CS1998 which means that 1998 is the number of the warning

Comment: Thanks. i was looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296.aspx and could not find it.